# Command Line Parser Library - Boolean Parameter

Tags: c#, nuget-package, command-line-parser

I try to pass a boolean parameter to a console application and process the value with the [Command Line Parser Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser).

```
[Option('c', "closeWindow", Required = true, HelpText = "Close the window.")]
public bool CloseWindow { get; set; }
```

I tried to pass the parameter as

```
-c false
-c False
-c "false"
-...
```

There are no differences, on each try I get `"true"` as value.

Can anyone tell me how I have to pass the parameter to get the boolean `false` value?

To avoid possible asks, there is a string option which is passed correctly:

```
[Option('s', "system", Required = true, HelpText = "Any help text")]
public string System { get; set; }
```

Comment: I would have thought Boolean parameters are present or not present. They don't require and argument - no idea how that works with `Required = true`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You don't need to add `True` or `False`. Using `-c` will evaluate to `True`. Not using it will evaluate to `False`. Somewhere in the documentation there is an example with `-v` for verbose output. But I can't find it right now. I guess `Required=true` is not necessary for Boolean options.

Comment: You are right, passing -c is evaluated as true if -c is not passed i get false. But what is if I want to use the "Required" option?

Comment: I think the library is not intended to use it this way, but you could make your option a string and then match the string to evaluate your Boolean. You can probably do that in the getter function of your option.

Comment: How about if default is 'True', how would this parameter make sense? Not specifying it means 'True' because of the default, specifying it means 'True', because is specified.

Comment: IMHO, that looks like a design fault

Comment: @momo, that's because it is.

Answer (score 47):

`bool?` behaves the way you want

with:

```cs
[Option('c', "closeWindow", Required = true, HelpText = "Close the window.")]
public bool? CloseWindow { get; set; }
```

the result will be:

```cs
-c false // -> false
-c true  // -> true
-c       // -> error
         // -> error if Required = true, null otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around to consider:

Change the names of the options so false is always the default. If you want "close window" to be the default, then the name of the option becomes `-w "keepWindowOpen"`.